# How can I open a non-resizable popup at a fixed position?

Tags: javascript, html, popup

See title. Using either javascript or pure HTML.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
window.open('url.htm','mywindow','width=400,height=200,left=0,top=100,screenX=0,screenY=100');
```

Comment: window.resizeTo(width, height);

Answer (score 2):

To make it non-resizable, just add a 'resizable=0' as one of the parameters.

```
    window.open('url.htm','mywindow','width=400,height=200,
left=0,top=100,screenX=0,screenY=100,resizable=0');
```

Answer (score 0):

You should carefully consider the use of non-resizable windows.

If the user has their default font size larger than the normal then your content won't fit as expected. In addition, if you specify a size larger than their screen you won't get the size you expect.

These situations are not that uncommon when you consider netbooks, handheld devices and computers that are attached to televisions.